# Getting "Max retries exceeded with URL: /v1.35/containers/create" error when using the Docker API for Python

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to start a docker image using the Docker package for Python and getting the following error:

`Getting "Max retries exceeded with URL: /v1.35/containers/create" error when using the Docker API for Python`

This is the command I run:

```
    self.container = self.docker_connector_client.container_run\
        (image="jenkins", version="latest", ports={'8080': '8081'})
```

The Docker deamon runs on port 3389 in a VM and I can definitely see it's running there.

When I run curl://localhost:3389 I see a response. But a curl from anywhere else I get an error.

The VM itself is running on GCP so perhaps there's some routing issues there but I fail to see anything wrong over there.
Thanks!

Comment: 1. Do you use `default` network? 2. Did you change firewall settings? 3. Which IP address does Docker run on? 4. Where do you run command?

Comment: 1. What do you mean "default" network? 2. I work at a large company, there maybe a FW tinkering that doing the problems here.. 3. It runs on a GCP machine. 4. I run the command on my Mac

Comment: 1. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc) you can find some information about VPC networking. 2. You should check if the necessary port is open 3. GCP machine also has an IP addresses, your service should be properly configured to make it accessible not only from `localhost` (which is limited by VM), check `curl` again but replace localhost with an internal IP of VM. 4. Please share your command.

Comment: Thanks! I think it’s an IT issue and I am trying to solve it through them

Comment: Thank you! Please let me know if you solve your issue and I post the answer that could be helpful for other community members.

Comment: Well, the problem was that the VM images I was using to run the code on had firewall in the start up script. So it wasn't really a Docker or Python API issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it was confirmed by @Pavel Zagalsky  there's no issues with Docker API for Python:

> the problem was that the VM images I was using to run the code on had
>   firewall in the start up script.